# Single page website with login control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a single page website (asp.net using c#) that displays some grid data when no user is logged in.
When a user presses login a popup control opens and they can login. when logged in extra functionality is available on that page.
Then after a period of inactivity (i.e no postback) I want the functionality to be disabled automatically on that page and a message stating you have been logged off.

Typical pages use a separate login page but that's not what I want.
is the above possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "easiest" route is to put a meta refresh in your page, that redirects to a logout page, then redirects you back.

Add the following to the head of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; url=yourlogoutpage.aspx">
```

After 60 seconds, your will automatically go to yourlogoutpage.aspx, where you will kill your session, and then redirect them back to this page.

Comment: so the meta refresh will redirect the user who is not logged in to a login page. is that going to work? i assume a redirect would only have to kick in after a user is logged in?

Comment: This would redirect them to a logOUT page, not login. If the person isn't logged in, then the logout page won't do anything other than redirect them back. If they are logged in, then kill their session and redirect them back. This isn't the most elegant solution by any means, but may be the easiest way to get you the basic functionality you need.

Comment: redirecting the page periodically when no user is logged in is not an option but thanks anyway

Comment: i want to reset that countdown if a postback is made other wise they will be redirected after 60 seconds regardlesss of whenter they are interacting with the webpage or not. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can add conditions if not logged in, display login fields, else, display the page contents.

Comment: Another option would be to have login information somewhere on the top or side that when hitting login it gives them full access and shows them as logged in. As for logging off at a set period of time i think you would need a timer of some sort and if the timer hits a certain value before post back then it logs them out next time they make a post back action.

Comment: hi,is there a possibility that you could show some sample code for this?

Comment: i would think that a timer is an excellent idea but it needs to start only when a user is logged in and resets only when a postback is made or when a partial postback is made or when an ajax postback is made. does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: You could add the meta refresh dynamically, if the person is logged in. See the asp.net HtmlMeta tag. That way it will only refresh if they are logged in.

Comment: but it will refres even if they are busy using the application! is there a way of resetting the countdown after any type of postback - standard or ajax etc

Comment: @user1438082 Can you elaborate more?

Comment: i ended up having a login page and using cookieless forms authentication with a meta tag to redirect to the login page after the idle time. what i really learned here was that microsoft has it done this way so stick with it.